# ¿Cómo cargar un js externo en angular 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs-2.0, materialize, system.js

Estoy usando angular 2 junto con **materialize** he puesto los scripts tanto de materialize como los de **jquery**. El problema es que cuando corro la aplicación con **npm start** el diseño se me desordena en los elementos que requieren js porque al parecer no carga los js...

```
<html>

<head>
 <base href="/">
 <title>Pagina 1</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <!-- css propios -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/css/materialize.min.css">

 <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
 <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
 <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
 <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
 <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
 <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
 <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
 <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>


  <script>
    System.import('app').catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
  </script>
 </head>
 <!-- 3. Display the application -->

 <body>
  <section-prin>Cargando...</section-prin>

  <!-- fw materialize -->
  <script src="asset/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="asset/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
 </body>

</html>
```

¿Por qué angular no me reconoce los script?

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Por favor mira en la ayuda [ask] , [qué puedo preguntar](/help/on-topic) y [qué no](/help/dont-ask). La pregunta tal cual la tienes ahora es muy amplia y es probable que sea cerrada. Te sugiero que la borres y cuando tengas una pregunta clara lo hagas con [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: mi duda esta relacionada con esta pregunta http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29387/cargar-script-externo-en-angular-2 @Awes0meM4n

Comment: Esa pregunta tampoco tiene respuesta. El problema en ambos casos es que crees que con lo que has puesto es suficiente pero lo normal, cuando se cierra una pregunta o no se contesta, es que falta información, no está clara la pregunta o el formato de esta web no es el adecuado (pregunta/respuesta). Te sugiero que investigues más para acotar tu problema, que pongas todo lo que has intentado y qué diferencia hay en cada intento y que hagas [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y utilices la opción de código para HTML con la parte problemática.

Comment: Intenta cargar los js desde un CDN, me parece que al compilar los recursos podrias ser incorrecta la ruta que tu definiste

Comment: ¿Para qué pones jQuery y Materialize al final? De todos modos estás cargando la mayoría de los scripts al principio, así que no tiene sentido el enfoque no-bloqueante. Dependiendo de la configuración de tu `systemjs.config.js`, lo más probable es que al ejecutarse busque un objeto global `$` que todavía no existe.

Answer (score 1):

Cargas directamente el archivo en el Index.html
ya sea en la cabezera o al final de la etiqueta body.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Y se agrega en el archivo .angular-cli.json, la carpeta donde se encuentra el archivo JavaScript.

```
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [            
        "js"
       ], ...
```

Vuelves a cargar el servicio y tu archivo JS ya estara incluido.

**Nota:** *Ninguna funcion, propiedad ni clase sera visible desde el contexto de Angular. Esto significa que no se pueden utilizar las funciones en angular 2.*

Answer (score 0):

La manera correcta de hacer esto es instalando las librerías con `npm` en tu proyecto y utilizándolas correctamente desde tus componentes.

Intenta instalando el *jQuery* y el *Materialize* con `npm`.

```
npm install materialize-css --save
npm install angular2-materialize --save

npm install jquery@^2.2.4 --save
npm install hammerjs --save
```

Aquí un enlace que explica cómo utilizar [*Materialize* en *Angular 2*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-materialize).

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que uses CDN en el caso del jquery, ya con materialize seria   `<script type="text/javascript" src="asset/materialize.min.js"></script>`

Comment: ¿Podrías dar más detalle de por qué esto solucionaría el problema?¿Y por qué esa ruta en lugar de la que tiene puesta el usuario en su código? Lee [ask] en el centro de ayuda para encontrar consejos sobre como mejorar esta respuesta.